# Bootstrap tooltips too large and square

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the bootstrap tooltips, instead of the small fitted black area like in the examples, I am experiencing a large outer rectangular box.  Just wondering if anyone has encountered this problem?

I am initializing with

```
 $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
```

My tooltip area is

```
<a id="button" style="float: left; margin-left:12px; margin-right:2px" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip"  href="#"></a>
```

Comment: I have this also - would love to know if you found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was being terribly dumb, there was another file in the project that was overriding some of the bootstrap css files.  I found this by using google chrome devloper tools>going to scripts, pausing while the hover box was up and then going back to elements, inspecting the hover and viewing which css files are being used.

Comment: Interestingly I found this too - I was having problems debugging with Chrome, and only discovered the problem when I changed the trigger to focus. In case anyone else finds the same problem, it was the DataTables css file that I needed to override.